# Code work on simulated data but not on real data in R

Tags: r

I simulated data.frames and wrought the code that works fine on simulated data, but when I am trying to use same code on real data it return last data in the list of data.frame only. Here is my simulated data and the code:

```
 call<- function(states, output) {
     df1<- data.frame(names=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), states=c("AK", "AL", "AR",   "AZ"), number=1:4)
     df1_state<- split(df1, df1$state)
     df2<- data.frame(names=c("e", "f", "g", "h"), states=c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ"), number=9:12)
     df2_state<- split(df2, df2$state)
     df3<- data.frame(names=c("i", "j", "k", "l"), states=c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ"), number=14:17)
     df3_state<- split(df3, df3$state)
     for (state in length(df1_state)) {
         if(output== "df1")
             print(b<- subset(df1_state[[states]], select= "names"))
         else if(output== "df2")
             print(c<- subset(df2_state[[states]], select= "names"))
         else
             print(d<- subset(df3_state[[states]], select= "names")) 
     }
 }
```

Does anyone has idea why code wouldn't work on real data?

Comment: `for (state in length(df1_state))` might be the problem. Add a `1` like this `1:length(df1_state))`

Comment: @platfort usually `for (states in seq_along(df1_state))` is preferable. (I've also changed `state` to `states`.)

Comment: If I use seq_along or 1:length is give me back hole list of states and I need just 1.

Comment: @brueggel If you need just one, you don't need a loop.